# Nuke Build in the Docker Image for .Net Core SDK and AspNetCore

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers, nuke-build

I have a .net core 3.1 API that uses Nuke Build to run tests and build the application.

we have created a Nuke task to run the dockerfile for this application.

We want to create an image with .Net/Asp.Net and Nuke Build in order to use this image to build our application in the Azure Pipeline.

Is it possible to install Nuke Build in an Docker Image with .Net SDK and AspNetCore ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a broad question, but yes, you can run a Nuke build in a Docker container. You don't even need to have the globaltool installed. You just need to run you _build project, so the container does need to have the dotnet SDK.